# Why did the Skrulls try shooting Carol?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

When Carol/Captain Marvel is using the phone outside Blockbusters she is attacked by a Skrull on a rooftop. The Skrull uses some sort of blaster to attack Carol so it was presumably an assassination attempt.

We later learn that

> the Skrulls really only want Carol so that she can decode the location of a spaceship where refugee Skrulls are hiding. As such, they wanted information from her. They didn't want to kill her.

Given this, wasn't shooting at her an extremely risky tactic? Were they actually trying to kill her at this stage, or just hurt her so that they could capture her?

Comment: it is quite possible that the shots were intended to pacify her rather than kill her. Given how tough she is, something capable of pacifying her would likely damage normal bricks and mortar.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is ever explained properly but we can make a couple of educated guesses as to the possible reasons this might have been.

1. To incapacitate her

   The Skrulls know that she is a big threat and so by incapacitating her they don't have as much of a threat to deal with. The Skrull could easily have been trying to hit her legs, or similar, so that she couldn't move as well so she was easier to catch and deal with. Remember that Vers is very powerful and so what would normally do a lot of damage to most things wouldn't do as much to her.
2. To minimise the opponents

   If I'm remembering correctly at the time the Skrull shoots at Vers she is stood near Fury and so the Skrull could easily have been trying to hit him to eliminate the possible opponents they have to fight.
3. Warning shot

   This is unlikely but it is possible it could have been a warning shot that intentionally misses to try and get her subdued so they could move in to take control. This one is unlikely though considering they know how powerful she is and they know how she reacted on the ship.
4. Revenge

   Again unlikely considering what the Skrull's wanted with Vers but it is possible the one who took the shot wasn't thinking properly and just wanted revenge considering what she had done on the ship.

Comment: RE: Point 2 it has been a while since I've seen the film so if someone's seen it recently and Fury wasn't actually nearby please let me know.

Comment: I saw it last night and he was standing next to her.